# Как работать с SOAP wsdl через PHP на примере службы ФедСФМ?

Tags: php, c#, xml, soap, wsdl

Мне нужно получать данные из удаленного сервиса, а именно из службы ФедСФМ https://portal.fedsfm.ru/Services/TerroristInfoService/TerroristInfoService.svc
Желательно через PHP или Go

Если я работаю через SoapClient в PHP, то мне пишет ошибку `Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.`

Пробовал менять настройку версии `$client = new SoapClient("https://service", ['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2]);` но в этом случае запрос просто виснет.

Написал в тех.поддержку сервиса и они мне ответили:

> Для вызова методов web-сервиса используется логин и пароль личного
>   кабинета.    Пример кода для вызова методов web-сервиса можно скачать
>   по ссылке:
>   http://fedsfm.ru/content/files/portal/TerroristInfoServiceExample.zip
>
> В примере используется unit-тест для платформы .NET Framework на языке
>   C#.    Также приложен конфигурационный файл, для установления
>   соединения к web-сервису

С C# мне не доводилось работать, и то что они прислали мне не помогло.

Я решил отправить xml строку в теле запроса с подставленными логином и паролем. Спросил у тех.поддежки как выглядит xml запроса.
Они прислали, некоторые значения были удалены, но структура осталась.:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action> <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:05bb7fb3-f172-4577-b033-5d594d13f107</a:MessageID> <a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>  </a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://portal.fedsfm.ru/Services/TerroristInfoService/TerroristInfoService.svc</a:To> <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>XXX</u:Created><u:Expires>XXX</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-cdc9772d-31d9-4a2c-89c7-6685369453c4-1"><o:Username>XXX</o:Username><o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXX</o:Password></o:UsernameToken</o:Security></s:Header><s:Body>    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:Entropy><t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-a59f96bb-9923-4548-b79a-5a48af821a81-1" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">XXX</t:BinarySecret></t:Entropy><t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Чуть отредактировал, заменил логин и пароль и отправил сформированный xml POST запросом...
В ответ получил xml, в котором был токен или точнее BinarySecret, что дальше делать не знаю. Куда теперь подставлять этот BinarySecret?

Спрашивал об этом тех.поддержку, они сказали "образец XML запроса предоставить нет возможности". И сказали, что нужно работать через Net Core. Но как так то?
Я поставил .Net Core, C#, VSCode на Linux. Но тут оказалось, что расширение, которое работает с SOAP работает только в Visual Studio.

Думаю, что нужно работать с запросами xml на прямую.

Как победить этот сервис?
Буду благодарен за любые совет

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**
Нашел интересную информацию здесь https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jws15/index.html
разбираюсь дальше...

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста! Ты пишешь, что саппорт тебе прислали примерный XML для генерации BinarySecret, а как выглядит этот XML? В том который ты приложил вроде как уже есть BinarySecret и по всей видимости это ответный XML.

Comment: @archisova это было давно. Я уже и не помню.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кому интересно, нашел ответ полностью решающий мою проблему...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218908/php-soap-client-with-wcf-badcontexttoken

Дублирую код из приложенной ссылки...

```
// TODO implement this by extending SoapClient class
// currently not implemented in it because request params are not generated correctly

/**
 * Client implementing SOAP wsHttpBinding with message security. <br>
 * NOTE: this is adapted to work for special needs of our client. It can be modified and there is a lot of work that jet needs to be done (nicer code, options and optimization).
 */

class WSSoap
{
    /**
     * Securit token request template
     */
    const STS_TEMPLATE = <<<X
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action><a:MessageID></a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1"></a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created></u:Created><u:Expires></u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id="_1"><o:Username></o:Username><o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"></o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:Entropy><t:BinarySecret Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce"></t:BinarySecret></t:Entropy><t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>
X;

    /**
     * Any action request template (mainly for headers)
     */
    const KPS_TEMPLATE = <<<X
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">n</a:Action><a:MessageID></a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1"></a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created></u:Created><u:Expires></u:Expires></u:Timestamp><c:SecurityContextToken xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc"><c:Identifier></c:Identifier></c:SecurityContextToken><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#_0"> <Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue></DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue></SignatureValue><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct"></o:Reference></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo></Signature></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body></s:Body></s:Envelope>
X;

    /**
     * Namespaces
     */
    const S11 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    const S12 = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
    const WSU = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
    const WSSE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    const WSSE11 = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wsecurity-secext-1.1.xsd";
    const WST = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust";
    const DS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
    const XENC = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#";
    const WSP = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy";
    const WSA = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
    const XS = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    const WSDL = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/";
    const SP = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702";
    const SC = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc";

    /**
     * STS Properties
     */
    protected $stsHostName;
    protected $stsEndpoint;
    protected $stsUsername;
    protected $stsPassword;
    protected $stsNamespace;

    /**
     * Binary secret used for generating request
     */
    protected $requestSecret;
    protected $rstrBinarySecret;
    protected $rstrKeyIdentifier;

    protected $token;
    protected $tokenReference;

    function __construct( $username, $password, $endpointURL, $namespace )
    {
        $this->stsUsername = $username;
        $this->stsPassword = $password;
        $this->stsHostName = parse_url( $endpointURL, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $this->stsEndpoint = $endpointURL;
        $this->stsNamespace = $namespace;
    }



    function request( $action, $fullActionName, $params )
    {
        $this->stsRequest();

        $kpsDom = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
        $kpsDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $kpsDom->loadXML(static::KPS_TEMPLATE);

        $kpsXpath = new \DOMXPath($kpsDom);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('S12', static::S12);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('WSA', static::WSA);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('WSU', static::WSU);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('WSSE', static::WSSE);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('XENC', static::XENC);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('DS', static::DS);
        $kpsXpath->registerNamespace('SC', static::SC);

        // Addressing

        $uuid = $this->uuid();

        $actionPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSA:Action");
        $messageIDPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSA:MessageID");
        $toPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSA:To");

        $actionPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $fullActionName;
        $messageIDPath->item(0)->nodeValue = sprintf("urn:uuid:%s", $uuid);
        $toPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->stsEndpoint;

        // Timestamp

        $time = time();

        $dateCreated = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $time);
        $dateExpires = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $time + (5 * 60));

        $timestampPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSU:Timestamp");
        $timestampDateCreatedPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSU:Timestamp/WSU:Created");
        $timestampDateExpiresPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSU:Timestamp/WSU:Expires");
        $timestampDateCreatedPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $dateCreated;
        $timestampDateExpiresPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $dateExpires;
        $timestampC14N = $timestampPath->item(0)->C14N(true, false);

        // DigestValue
        $digestValue = base64_encode(hash('sha1', $timestampC14N, true));
        $digestValuePath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/DS:Signature/DS:SignedInfo/DS:Reference/DS:DigestValue");
        $digestValuePath->item(0)->nodeValue = $digestValue;

        // Signature
        $signaturePath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/DS:Signature/DS:SignedInfo");
        $signatureValuePath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/DS:Signature/DS:SignatureValue");
        $signatureC14N = $signaturePath->item(0)->C14N(true, false);

        $psBinary = $this->psha1( $this->requestSecret, $this->rstrBinarySecret );
        $signatureValue = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $signatureC14N, $psBinary, true));
        $signatureValuePath->item(0)->nodeValue = $signatureValue;

        // token reference
        $securityContextTokenReference = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/DS:Signature/DS:KeyInfo/WSSE:SecurityTokenReference/WSSE:Reference");
        $securityContextTokenReference->item(0)->setAttribute('URI', "#$this->tokenReference");
        // token ID
        $tokenPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/SC:SecurityContextToken");
        $tokenPath->item(0)->setAttribute('u:Id', $this->tokenReference);
        // token
        $tokenPath = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/SC:SecurityContextToken/SC:Identifier");
        $tokenPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->token;

        // Message
        $bodyElemet = $kpsXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Body")->item(0);
        $root = $kpsDom->createElementNS( $this->stsNamespace, $action );

        foreach( $params as $name => $value ) {
            $root->appendChild( $kpsDom->createElement( $name, $value ) );
        }

        $bodyElemet->appendChild( $root );
        $kpsRequest = $kpsDom->saveXML();

        // Request
        try {
            $stsResponse = $this->execCurl( $kpsRequest );
        } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
            throw $e;
        }

        return $stsResponse;
    }


    /**
     * Performs a STS request
     *
     * @param string $location Request location
     */
    protected function stsRequest()
    {
        $rstXml = static::STS_TEMPLATE;

        $rstDom = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
        $rstDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $rstDom->loadXML($rstXml);

        $rstXpath = new \DOMXPath($rstDom);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('S12', static::S12);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('WSA', static::WSA);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('WSU', static::WSU);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('WSSE', static::WSSE);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('XENC', static::XENC);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('DS', static::DS);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('WST', static::WST);
        $rstXpath->registerNamespace('WSP', static::WSP);

        // Addressing

        $uuid = $this->uuid();

        $messageIDPath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSA:MessageID");
        $toPath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSA:To");

        $messageIDPath->item(0)->nodeValue = sprintf("urn:uuid:%s", $uuid);
        $toPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->stsEndpoint;

        // Timestamp

        $time = time();

        $dateCreated = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $time);
        $dateExpires = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $time + (5 * 60));

        $timestampDateCreatedPath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSU:Timestamp/WSU:Created");
        $timestampDateExpiresPath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSU:Timestamp/WSU:Expires");
        $timestampDateCreatedPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $dateCreated;
        $timestampDateExpiresPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $dateExpires;

        // Credentials

        $usernamePath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSSE:UsernameToken/WSSE:Username");
        $passwordPath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Header/WSSE:Security/WSSE:UsernameToken/WSSE:Password");

        $usernamePath->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->stsUsername;
        $passwordPath->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->stsPassword;

        // Set binary key
        $this->requestSecret = uniqid();
        $binaryKeyPath = $rstXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Body/WST:RequestSecurityToken/WST:Entropy/WST:BinarySecret");
        $binaryKeyPath->item(0)->nodeValue = base64_encode( $this->requestSecret );

        // Endpoint
        $stsRequest = $rstDom->saveXML();

        // Request
        try {
            $stsResponse = $this->execCurl( $stsRequest );
        } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
            throw $e;
        }

        $rstrDom = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
        $rstrDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $rstrDom->loadXML($stsResponse);

        $rstrXpath = new \DOMXPath($rstrDom);

        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('S12', static::S12);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('WSA', static::WSA);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('WSU', static::WSU);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('WSSE', static::WSSE);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('XENC', static::XENC);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('DS', static::DS);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('WST', static::WST);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('WSP', static::WSP);
        $rstrXpath->registerNamespace('SC', static::SC);

        // parse security context token
        $securityContextTokenReference = $rstrXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Body/WST:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/WST:RequestedSecurityToken/SC:SecurityContextToken");
        $this->tokenReference = $securityContextTokenReference->item(0)->getAttribute('u:Id');

        $securityContextToken = $rstrXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Body/WST:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/WST:RequestedSecurityToken/SC:SecurityContextToken/SC:Identifier");
        $this->token = $securityContextToken->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $securityContextToken = $rstrXpath->query("//S12:Envelope/S12:Body/WST:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/WST:Entropy/WST:BinarySecret");

        $this->rstrBinarySecret = base64_decode( $securityContextToken->item(0)->nodeValue );
    }

    protected function execCurl( $request )
    {
        // Request
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->stsEndpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // disable SSL verification - re-enable if needed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Host: " . $this->stsHostName,
            "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Length: " . strlen( $request ),
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if ( $response === false ) {
            throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Generates UUID
     *
     * @return string UUID
     */
    protected function uuid()
    {
        return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x', //
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), //
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), //
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), //
            mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000, //
            mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000, //
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), //
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), //
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff) //
        );
    }


    /**
     * Calculate psha1 hash used for signature generation
     * @param unknown $clientSecret
     * @param unknown $serverSecret
     * @param number $sizeBits
     * @return string
     */
    protected function psha1($clientSecret, $serverSecret, $sizeBits = 256)
    {
        $sizeBytes = $sizeBits / 8;

        $hmacKey = $clientSecret;
        $hashSize = 160; // HMAC_SHA1 length is always 160
        $bufferSize = $hashSize / 8 + strlen($serverSecret);
        $i = 0;

        $b1 = $serverSecret;
        $b2 = "";
        $temp = null;
        $psha = array();

        while ($i < $sizeBytes) {
            $b1 = hash_hmac('SHA1', $b1, $hmacKey, true);
            $b2 = $b1 . $serverSecret;
            $temp = hash_hmac('SHA1', $b2, $hmacKey, true);

            for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($temp); $j++) {
                if ($i < $sizeBytes) {
                    $psha[$i] = $temp[$j];
                    $i++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return implode("", $psha);
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить что-то подобное в запросе:

```
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">https://some.url/NamespaceName/IServices/CheckTransaction</a:Action>
...
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <CheckTransaction xmlns="https://sime.url/ActionToDo">
        <TransactionID>1234567</TransactionID>
    </CheckTransaction>
</s:Body>
```

Клиентский код:

```
$url = 'https://some.url/Services.svc';
$namespace = 'https://some.url/NamespaceName'; // this is action namespace you need, since there is no WSDL parsing you need to set it by yourself

try {
    $c = new WSSoap( $username, $password, $url, $namespace );
    $params = array(
        'TransactionID' => '1234567'
    );
    $r = $c->request( 'CheckTransaction', 'https://some.url/NamespaceName/IServices/CheckTransaction', $params ); // also applies - no WSDL parsing so we need to set params
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```